# Yield showing syntax error ; is missing in javascript;

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-harmony

I am writing the simple function of generator

```
function simpleGenerator(){
  yield "first";
  yield "second";
  yield "third";
};
var g = simpleGenerator();
console.log(g.next());
```

it is giving for the line of yield --

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

i am unable to get the reason for showing error...
if i use return like

```
function simpleGenerator(x){
 while(true){
  var a=x*2;
  return a;
 }
}
var g = simpleGenerator(2);
console.log(g);
```

It is working properly,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generator functions have to be defined like this

```
function * simpleGenerator() {    # Note the `*` after `function` keyword
    yield "first";
    yield "second";
    yield "third";
};
var g = simpleGenerator();
console.log(g.next());
# { value: 'first', done: false }
```

Quoting from the [ECMA 6's Harmony page for Generator functions](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3agenerators#syntax),

> The function syntax is extended to add an optional * token:
>
> ```
> FunctionDeclaration:
>     "function" "*"? Identifier "(" FormalParameterList? ")" "{" FunctionBody "}"   FunctionExpression:
>     "function" "*"? Identifier? "(" FormalParameterList? ")" "{" FunctionBody "}"
> ```
>
> A function with a * token is known as a generator function. The following two unary operators are only allowed in the immediate body of a generator function (i.e., in the body but not
>   nested inside another function):
>
> ```
> AssignmentExpression:
>     ...
>     YieldExpression
>
> YieldExpression:
>     "yield" ("*"? AssignmentExpression)?
> ```
>
> An early error is raised if a yield or yield* expression occurs in a non-generator function.YieldExpression:

Comment: @lyschoening It is optional because you can drop `*` to define a normal function.

Comment: you are right. I still don't know if that is the cause of the issue here because the `yield` keyword already existed in Javascript 1.7 as implemented by Mozilla and the enclosing function did not require a `*` back then.

Comment: @lyschoening This is the standard going forward. So, if FF does differently it is a non-standard feature or not a ECMA standard complaint feature :-)

Comment: I wonder what browser OP is using. There is a SyntaxError in Chrome when the flag is missing, but it is a `SyntaxError: Unexpected string`

Comment: I get: SyntaxError: function statement requires a name

Comment: @erjoalgo Which environment is that?

Comment: I was using iceweasel. Probably the javascript version was pre-yield support. I couldn't find a sensible way to iterate through one of these generators, so I ended up skipping yield altogether.

Comment: @erjoalgo Try using the latest Node.js development version, with harmony options :-)